# How to create a white-green button like a button from http://cmsaspnet.com/forum.aspx page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, hyperlink

Can you point me in the right direction to create blinking white and green links (which appear like buttons) which are englarged on hover, like from here http://cmsaspnet.com/forum.aspx#Focused ?

[image: description]
**I'm very new to web-programming so be tolerant, please.**

I use Microsoft Web Developer 2010.

Comment: please bear in mind that the general opinion of blinking effects on the web these days is that people hate them. They were very common 10 or 15 years ago when everyone was putting up awful sites on Geocities, but in general it's best to avoid blinking effects these days, or at least keep them to an absolute minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **The spinning "button":** [Demo for 7 javascript-effect alternatives using CSS 3 for webkit browsers](http://webdeveloperjuice.com/demos/css/css3effects.html) 
  *(The spin block should
  help you out if you would adjust it yourself abit)*
- **Flashing button:** [Making your signup button flash with jquery](http://www.imkazu.com/making-your-signup-button-flash-with-jquery/)
  (You should set the interval to 99999+)

Everything will work out if you just play around with it.

Just pretend you're in science class.